# get chrome extension to access a given link and search for existing links on that page.

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

How do I get a get chrome extension to access a given link and search for other existing links on that given link's page?

I have an array of links, and I want it go to each of those links and search for other links then download those links.

Comment: I used document.getElementsbyId to get a links of links. But I have no idea how to acually access those links.

Comment: You could load them in `iframes`. In any case, what you are after does not sound like a task well suited for a Chrome Extension.

Comment: could I pass the links to a program that uses python or ruby? Do you know how I could do this?

Comment: could I use an xmlhttprequest?

Comment: Yes a program in Java/python/ruby/php (even a bash script using curl) would be (imo) abetter option. Using XMLHttpRequest might lead into problems (or increased complexity due to Content Security Policies) but apart from that you could probably get it to work in the end.